# PHP class inheriting Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am new to PHP and I am using Codeigniter. I have a PHP file and I did the following as OOP:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
 class Producat 
 {
     var $price;
     var $title;
     var $name;

   public function setProducatName ($nam)
   {
    $this->name=$nam;
   } 

   public function getProduactName()
  {
    echo $this->name;
  }
  public function setAttribute ($price1,$title1) 
  {
    $this->price=$price1;
    $this->title=$title1;

  }

class  Fruniture extends Producat 
 {
    var $size;
    var $material;
 } 
  class  Cddvd extends Producat 
 {
    var $size;
    var $manufacuter;
 }
```

I had database called saied in my phpmyadmin.

I am trying to insert the title of the product to database and then also get the name from database in the class.

1. like : how to connect to database in the class. How to communicate with database right in product class, but it would be preferable if all database functions will be separated
2. I need for the material attribute just to have 2 choices (plastic or wood ) ?
3. Function to get all product attributes Size attribute for CD/DVD should always have “MB” appended to it.

Note: I made all the configure to connect to database

Answer (score 0):

you're missing your magic `__construct` function

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

That is not the exact way of using the CI php framework.
First you need to understand the basics.

1. Controller - this is a class that handles the uri.
2. Model - class that communicate into database.
3. Views - displays the HTML.

Example Controller:

```
<?php
class Product extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
        $this->load->view("products");
    }
}
?>
```

Example Model:

```
   class Product extends CI_Model {

        var $title   = '';
        var $content = '';
        var $date    = '';

        function __construct()
        {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function get_all()
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('entries');
            return $query->result();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove this `<<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. in your getter (getProduactName for exemple) use return not echo
3. instead of setAttribute  set __construct
4. extend codeIgniter Model

the code most be somthing like :

```
<?php
 class Producat extends CI_Model
 {
     var $price;
     var $title;
     var $name;

function __construct($price1,$title1) {
parent::__construct();
 $this->price=$price1;
    $this->title=$title1;
}
   public function setProducatName ($nam)
   {
    $this->name=$nam;
   } 

   public function getProduactName()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }
  public function setAttribute ($price1,$title1) 
  {
    $this->price=$price1;
    $this->title=$title1;

  }
function insert_indb(){
$data[] = ["title"=>$this->title];
$data[] = ["name"=>$this->name];
$data[] = ["price"=>$this->price];
$this->db->insert('students', $data);
}
```